# Click function on dynamic button, live / on not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button, dynamic

I am trying to run a function when a dynamically generated button is clicked. It does for some reason not seem to work, whatever method I try using.

**JavaScript**

```
//Generating the button
$('<div><h3>Back<h3></div>')
  .attr('class', 'rtext btn arrowback').attr('role', 'button').attr('id', '2')
  .appendTo($(".row1")).hide().delay(800).fadeIn(1000);

//function when button is clicked
$(".row1").on("click", ".arrowback", function(){
    var userID = this.id;
    alert(userID);
});
```

I have tried using .on as above, I have tried using .live as:

```
$(".arrowback").live("click", function(){
   var userID = this.id;
   alert(userID);
});
```

Yet nothing seem to work. Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: Can you please put the html code?

Comment: Ah, I gladly would, but the .row1 that my button appends to, is dynamically generated too, so I'm afraid that I cannot add that html as well. Is that perhaps the problem? That both child and parent are dynamically generated?

Comment: Actually I want that html (.row1) code where you declared the class .row1 and where you want to append the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I have now solved it, if both parent and child are dynamically generated, the below will function:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".arrowback", function(){
    var userID = this.id;
    alert(userID);     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating elements dynamically also allow to bind event to the recent element created.

Look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/andtankian/pen/dXpZPR

```
$('div').append("<div></div>");
$('div>div').addClass("row1");

//Generating the button
$('<div><h3>Back<h3></div>')
  .attr('class', 'rtext btn arrowback').attr('role', 'button').attr('id', '2')
  .appendTo($(".row1")).hide().delay(800).fadeIn(1000);

//function when button is clicked
$(".row1").on("click", ".arrowback", function(){
    var userID = this.id;
    alert(userID);
});
```

I simulated your environment and everything works fine.